# JSON_EXRACT vs native SQL query

Tags: mysql, json

I was originally going to ask this on SO, but thought better of it, so I am trying my hand here.

I have searched this out and can't find any definitive data.  I have a MySQL table that looks like:

```
| id |  type  |  value  |
```

The `value` field contains a JSON string and the column type is JSON.  My JSON contains identification information that I'd like to be able to call on IE

```
WHERE json_extract(value, '$.contractor_id')='12345'
```

What are the performance ramifications doing it this way instead of just creating a separated `contractor_id` column?  This specific table has ~500,000 rows.  The `contractor_id` isn't a key-able or index-able field either ... So is it really 6 one way half dozen another?  Or is there a specific reason I need to create a separated column for performance sake?

Comment: JSON (CSV, XML, etc.) usage is denormalization formally. So its using is reasonable only when the JSON value is either stored or retrieved. It is must be processed then data normalization is preferred solution. *he contractor_id isn't a key-able or index-able field either ...* Read about generated columns and about multi-valued indices.

Comment: Why do you say "isn't a key-able or index-able"??

Comment: I suppose it can be indexed .. But it wouldn't help much with overhead or performance, because a contractor can have multiple entries in the table .. So it isn't unique and every contractor can have hundreds of entries in theory ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your version of MySQL.

In MySQL 5.7, it was possible to create a virtual column based on the json_extract() expression, and an index on that virtual column. But you must search using that virtual column to use the index.

```
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, type text, value json);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable set value = '{"contractor_id": "12345"}';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table mytable add column contractor_id int as (json_extract(value, '$.contactor_id')), add index (contractor_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
    
mysql> explain select * from mytable where json_extract(value, '$.contractor_id')='12345';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain select * from mytable where contractor_id='12345';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | contractor_id | contractor_id | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can create virtual indexes on expressions, without needing to create the virtual column first. But there are restrictions on indexing json expressions.

```
mysql> alter table mytable add index ((json_unquote(json_extract(value, '$.contractor_id'))));
ERROR 3757 (HY000): Cannot create a functional index on an expression that returns a BLOB or TEXT. Please consider using CAST.
```

So I have to cast it to an integer:

```
mysql> alter table mytable add index ((cast(json_unquote(json_extract(value, '$.contractor_id')) as signed)));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

The optimizer seems to be able to figure this out, and I can make use of the index even based on part of the expression.

```
mysql> explain select * from mytable where json_extract(`value`,'$.contractor_id')=12345;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | functional_index | functional_index | 9       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

But all these idiosyncrasies regarding JSON in an RDBMS are a bother. You end up being forced into solutions that are complex and require deep understanding of advanced features.

Why not just create `contractor_id` or any other attribute you want to be indexed as a normal column? That's far simpler.

The more I see people using JSON in MySQL, the more I feel it is one of the worst and most unnecessary features to be added to the product.

There are cases where you might genuinely need to have a "semi-structured" column, when you have to store data that has variable fields. JSON is good for this, or XML, or YAML, or protobufs, etc. But then making them support SQL operations as if they are normal columns is not a good strategy.

Use normal columns for attributes that you want to search or sort by. If you must, use JSON only as a "payload" column to store the variable data.

You might also like my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong). I developed that presentation before MySQL 8.0, so it doesn't cover expression indexes, but other points are still true, like JSON requiring a lot more space to store the same data.

Comment: I am leaning toward agreeing with you, since the only search parameter is going to be BY `contractor_id` and `type` -- The JSON is used as a "configuration" that can be wildly different based on "type" --  But it contains the contractor_id.  I think I will just add the column, and build a SQL call that will fill in the Ids and be done with it!